# Unable to figure out which npm dependency to resolve

Tags: python, node.js, npm, macros, alteryx

I am trying to create a tool in Alteryx, using python. I am following the steps outlined in their [guide](https://alteryx.github.io/ayx-python-sdk/getting_started.html), and am facing a problem which is specific to npm.

I have looked around on how to solve this, but don't understand which dependency needs to be installed and which directory would be suitable etc, would appreciate any help in this regard.

````
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency\n
npm WARN While resolving: @formatjs/intl@1.11.1\n
npm WARN Found: typescript@3.9.7\n
npm WARN node_modules/typescript\n
npm WARN   dev typescript@"3.9.7" from the root project\n
npm WARN   2 more (ts-loader, ts-loader)\n
npm WARN \n
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:\n
npm WARN peerOptional typescript@"^4.2" from @formatjs/intl@1.11.1\n
npm WARN node_modules/@formatjs/intl\n
npm WARN   @formatjs/intl@"1.11.1" from react-intl@5.18.1\n
npm WARN   node_modules/react-intl\n
npm WARN \nnpm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.8.4\n
npm WARN node_modules/typescript\n
npm WARN   peerOptional typescript@"^4.2" from @formatjs/intl@1.11.1\n
npm WARN   node_modules/@formatjs/intl\n
npm WARN     @formatjs/intl@"1.11.1" from react-intl@5.18.1\n
npm WARN     node_modules/react-intl\nnpm ERR! code ERESOLVE\n
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve\n
npm ERR! \n
npm ERR! While resolving: react-intl@5.18.1\n
npm ERR! Found: typescript@3.9.7\n
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript\n
npm ERR!   dev typescript@"3.9.7" from the root project\n
npm ERR!   peer typescript@"*" from ts-loader@8.3.0\n
npm ERR!   node_modules/@alteryx/react-comms/node_modules/ts-loader\n
npm ERR!     ts-loader@"^8.0.14" from @alteryx/react-comms@1.0.0\n
npm ERR!     node_modules/@alteryx/react-comms\n
npm ERR!       @alteryx/react-comms@"^1.0.0" from the root project\n
npm ERR!   1 more (ts-loader)\n
npm ERR! \n
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:\n
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^4.2" from react-intl@5.18.1\n
npm ERR! node_modules/react-intl\n
npm ERR!   react-intl@"^5.8.1" from the root project\n
npm ERR!   peer react-intl@"^5.8.1" from @alteryx/ui@1.0.0\n
npm ERR!   node_modules/@alteryx/ui\n
npm ERR!     @alteryx/ui@"^1.0.0" from the root project\n
npm ERR! \n
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.8.4\n
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript\n
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^4.2" from react-intl@5.18.1\n
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-intl\n
npm ERR!     react-intl@"^5.8.1" from the root project\n
npm ERR!     peer react-intl@"^5.8.1" from @alteryx/ui@1.0.0\n
npm ERR!     node_modules/@alteryx/ui\n
npm ERR!       @alteryx/ui@"^1.0.0" from the root project\n
npm ERR! \n
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry\n
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps\n
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.\n
npm ERR! \n
npm ERR! See C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.\n\n
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\n
npm ERR!     C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_logs\\2022-10-09T11_02_33_206Z-debug-0.log\n'```
````

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in react dependencies, alteryx uses legacy modules of react.

After creation SDK, adjust the script ..Python\Python38\site-packages\ayx_plugin_cli\ayx_workspace\doit\build_tasks\generate_artifact.py

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfMsH.png)

instead of "install", set "install --legacy-peer-deps" and recreate plugin(delete the old one)

I hope, it will help you